# Loop Video GPUImage 2

Tags: swift, video, gpuimage

I am trying to display a looped *filtered* video to the user using GPUImage 2

With GPUImage 1 i could do the following

```
player = AVPlayer()

let pathURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)

playerItem = AVPlayerItem(with: pathURL)

player.replaceCurrentItem(with: playerItem)

moive = GPUImageMovie(playerItem: playerItem)

movie.playAtActualSpeed = true 

movie.addTarget(filter)
filter.addTarget(filterView)

movie.startProcessing()

player.play()
```

I would also add in viewDidLoad

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: .AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: self.player.currentItem, queue: .main) { (notification) in
    self.player.seek(to: kCMTimeZero)
    self.player.play()
}
```

This would result in the video looping properly.

Even adding `movie.shouldRepeat = true` did the trick for the filtering part.

However with GPUImage 2 i am unable to achieve the same result

```
movie = try MovieInput(url: movieURL, playAtActualSpeed: true, loop: true)
```

The above does not result in a loop.

There are two outcomes i am looking to achieve one being the video looping consistently for the user to view and the second is saving the loop video as an extended video. Help with either is greatly appreciated.